# Change conditional class instance of child class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a parent class called `Organism` which has a class attribute called `isIntelligent` and I create a variable called `fitness` based on the value of the class attribute `isIntelligent` likewise:

```py
class Organism:

    isIntelligent = False
    
    def __init__(self):
        #some variables defined here


    if isIntelligent:

        @property
        def fitness(self):
            return 0
```

Now, I want to create two child classes, for example `Rabbit` and `Fox`, I want Rabbits to be intelligent and Foxs to be not. In accordance to that they should have the `fitness` property.

I tried to change the value of the `isIntelligent` variable inside the child classes likewise:

```py
class Rabbit(Organism):

    isIntelligent = True

class Fox(Organism):

    isIntelligent = False
```

However, when I run the code and I expect the Rabbit objects to have the `fitness` variable, but they do not.

What would be the correct way to go about this ?

Comment: `isIntelligent` isn't a class instance, it's a class attribute.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for pointing it out, I always get confused with the terms. Corrected it.

Comment: The line `if isIntelligent:` is only executed when your `Organism` class is loaded for the first time. What do you think of creating a method `isFitness` in `Organism` that returns True if `isIntelligent` is True?

Comment: Typically, you'd define  a subclass `class IntelligentOrganism(Organism): @property def fitness(self): return 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that isn't in a method is executed when the class is defined, so it can't be dependent on the instance. You need to put the condition inside the property method.

```
@property
def fitness(self):
    if self.isIntelligent:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```